# Why my `text-justify` class do not line feed?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Why my `text-justify` class do not line feed?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <p class="text-justify">abcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmn</p>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The text in one line, why it do not wrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are no spaces in your text; all that gibberish is one long word and so it can't break.

Your code works, you just have to use real words (or at least hit the space bar when typing random characters) when testing.

I always use [Lorem Ipsum](https://www.lipsum.com), and have a macro set up so that I just type `lipsum` and a full paragraph will be inserted where my cursor is.

```
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/core.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="text-justify">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, what if the OP does have a valid reason to have long words or they might have a narrow block only...?

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have one very long word and the `text-align: justify` property avoid breaking words. You need to add some spaces to make it justified.

Comment: I don't understand, what if the OP does have a valid reason to have long words or they might have a narrow block only...?

Answer (score 1):

Style your block elements with `word-wrap: break-word;` to allow line breaks inside words.

```css
.col-md-12>p { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p class="text-justify">abcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmn</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `word-wrap` to wrap'em up

Why do you need align the text justified when you have only one word!!

```css
p{
  word-wrap:break-word;
  }
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p class="text-justify">abcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklmn</p>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```